# Need Direction - Web Bot Creation

Tags: web

I want to create something that will look at a specific location on a website and read the value at this location. Then take that value and put it into a already created block of text.

What do I need to start researching to create something like that?  Simple direction such as key words to Google and such would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to get the value from your own website or someone else's website?

If you want to get the value from an HTML element, you can easily do so using **Javascript/jQuery**.

If you are looking to write a script that parses the HTML from somebody else's website, you will need a **HTML parser**. *If you plan to use Python, look into Beautiful Soup*.